Handling Noise in Regression Problem
Problem Description
Consider a discrete time linear time-invariant (LTI) system with unknown mathematical model. The system is of order $ n $ and has $ m $ inputs and $ p $ outputs. The input and output vectors at time $ k $ are denoted by $ u_k $ and $ y_k $, respectively.
The vectors $u_N(k)$ and $y_N(k)$ are defined as follows:
$$
u_N(k) =
\begin{bmatrix}
u_k \\
u_{k+1} \\
\vdots \\
u_{k+N-1}
\end{bmatrix},
\quad
y_N(k) =
\begin{bmatrix}
y_k \\
y_{k+1} \\
\vdots \\
y_{k+N-1}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Matrices $ Y $ and $ G $ are made as follows for $ I  \geq (2m + p)N $ and $ k \geq N$:
$$
Y = [y_N(k), y_N(k+1), \dots, y_N(k+I)]
$$
$$
G = 
\begin{bmatrix}
u_N(k-N) & \dots & u_N(k-N+I) \\
y_N(k-N) & \dots & y_N(k-N+I) \\
u_N(k) & \dots & u_N(k+I)
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Assuming the matrix $ GG^T $ is always invertible, the unknown matrix $ F $ can be computed as:
$$
F G = Y \quad \Rightarrow \quad F = YG(GG^T)^{-1}
$$
Assuming $k=N=n$, by choosing any value for $I$ such that $ I \geq (2m + p)N $, the answer obtained for matrix $F$ is always a fixed value.
Handling Noise
If there is noise added to the system's output, the calculated matrix $ F $ will change.
In the noiseless case, it can be mathematically proven that there exists a constant $ F $ that always satisfies the equation $ FG = Y $. However, if, for instance, measurement noise is added to the system's output, the existence of such a relationship is no longer guaranteed. In this case, we typically seek an $ \hat{F} $ such that $ \hat{F}G $ is as close as possible to $ Y $ (or is a good approximation of $ Y $). Depending on how we define the criterion for this closeness (or good approximation), different solutions for $ \hat{F} $ can be found. Computing $ \hat{F} $ from the equation $ \hat{F} = YG^T (GG^T)^{-1} $ is merely one possible method.
Example
Consider an LTI system with one input and one output, with the following input-output data:
$$
u = \{0.0123, 0.0504, 0.0347, 0.0092, 0.0148, 0.0198, 0.0672, 0.0432\}
$$
$$
y = \{-0.8830, 1.0600, -1.3300, 1.5824, -1.9272, 2.3241, -2.8361, 3.3802\}
$$
For $ I = 3 $:
$$
Y = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1.0600 & -1.3300 & 1.5824 & -1.9272
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
G =
\begin{bmatrix}
0.0123 & 0.0504 & 0.0347 & 0.0092 \\
-0.8830 & 1.0600 & -1.3300 & 1.5824 \\
0.0504 & 0.0347 & 0.0092 & 0.0148
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
F = 
\begin{bmatrix}
-0.8830 & -1.2128 & 0.0000
\end{bmatrix}
$$
For $ I = 4 $:
$$
Y = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1.0600 & -1.3300 & 1.5824 & -1.9272 & 2.3241
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
G =
\begin{bmatrix}
0.0123 & 0.0504 & 0.0347 & 0.0092 & 0.0148 \\
-0.8830 & 1.0600 & -1.3300 & 1.5824 & -1.9272 \\
0.0504 & 0.0347 & 0.0092 & 0.0148 & 0.0198
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
F = 
\begin{bmatrix}
-0.8830 & -1.2128 & 0.0000
\end{bmatrix}
$$
For $ I = 5 $:
$$
Y = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1.0600 & -1.3300 & 1.5824 & -1.9272 & 2.3241 & -2.8361
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
G =
\begin{bmatrix}
0.0123 & 0.0504 & 0.0347 & 0.0092 & 0.0148 & 0.0198 \\
-0.8830 & 1.0600 & -1.3300 & 1.5824 & -1.9272 & 2.3241 \\
0.0504 & 0.0347 & 0.0092 & 0.0148 & 0.0198 & 0.0672
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
F = 
\begin{bmatrix}
-0.8830 & -1.2128 & 0.0000
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Now, let's introduce Gaussian noise to the system's output. The noise is modeled as random values from a Gaussian distribution, so the output is modified as:
$$
y_k = y_k \left(1 + 0.1 \times \frac{\text{randn()}}{3} \right)
$$
Given the same input sequence:
$$
u = \{0.0123, 0.0504, 0.0347, 0.0092, 0.0148, 0.0198, 0.0672, 0.0432\}
$$
$$
y = \{-0.8907, 1.0282, -1.2344, 1.5873, -1.8661, 2.4150, -3.0002, 3.3383\}
$$
For this noisy case, the matrix $ \hat{F} = YG(GG^T)^{-1}$ is calculated for different values of $ I $.
For $ I = 3 $:
$$
Y = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1.0282 & -1.2344 & 1.5873 & -1.8661
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
G =
\begin{bmatrix}
0.0123 & 0.0504 & 0.0347 & 0.0092 \\
-0.8907 & 1.0282 & -1.2344 & 1.5873 \\
0.0504 & 0.0347 & 0.0092 & 0.0148
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
\hat{F} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1.9741 & -1.2092 & -1.4986
\end{bmatrix}
$$
For $ I = 4 $:
$$
Y = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1.0282 & -1.2344 & 1.5873 & -1.8661 & 2.4150
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
G =
\begin{bmatrix}
0.0123 & 0.0504 & 0.0347 & 0.0092 & 0.0148 \\
-0.8907 & 1.0282 & -1.2344 & 1.5873 & -1.8661 \\
0.0504 & 0.0347 & 0.0092 & 0.0148 & 0.0198
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
\hat{F} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
2.1775 & -1.2393 & -1.1637
\end{bmatrix}
$$
For $ I = 5 $:
$$
Y = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1.0282 & -1.2344 & 1.5873 & -1.8661 & 2.4150 & -3.0002
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
G =
\begin{bmatrix}
0.0123 & 0.0504 & 0.0347 & 0.0092 & 0.0148 & 0.0198 \\
-0.8907 & 1.0282 & -1.2344 & 1.5873 & -1.8661 & 2.4150 \\
0.0504 & 0.0347 & 0.0092 & 0.0148 & 0.0198 & 0.0672
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
\hat{F} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
2.0541 & -1.2366 & -0.9325
\end{bmatrix}
$$
As observed, the matrix $ \hat{F} $ values deviate from the noiseless case due to the presence of noise.
My Question:
How we can mitigate the effect of this deviation (noise) without explicitly modeling the system?

Hi: It sounds somewhat like regression but the notation is not standard ( sounds like you're coming from DSP viewpoint possibly ? ) and you never wrote down the original model. My guess is that, if you write down the original model ( i.e: $Y = $ what + what ), then people will be able to relate your notation to the more standard regression notation and you'll get more responses and insights.

Least squares regression is the standard method--depending on what you might mean by "explicitly modeling the system."  Could you clarify that phrase?
